# Optimizing the Org

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow, process-builder, performance, sales-cloud

I have been working on an org which have a lot of automation on the objects especially leads. There are more than 10 process builders and triggers each. They all work for different processes and perform different tasks. I am looking for ways by which this system can be more organised.
I had a thought, that I should combine process builders based on when they are run. But I am not sure if that will make any difference. Do suggest me possible ideas or methods using which I can optimize the system.
Thank You.

Comment: Ideally, you should only have one process builder and one trigger per object. If it’s a smaller org and the admin is also a developer, I would personally convert the process builders to a trigger as well since triggers are much more efficient. But that all depends how much time you have and how important optimization is to you.

Comment: That does make sense! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Organisation is key to optimisation. Here are a few things I would suggest...

**Audit & Documentation**

- Before making changes, document all existing automation. Understand the purpose of each process builder, trigger, workflow, etc. This will help you identify redundancies, conflicts, and areas of improvement.

**Reduce Redundancies:**

- After documenting, identify any overlapping or redundant processes. If two process builders do similar things, consider merging them.

**Consolidate automations where possible:**

- Combining process builders, for example, based on when they run (e.g., all "before insert" or "after update" actions) can help in reducing the number of evaluation cycles. However, ensure that consolidating them doesn't make the process builder too complex or difficult to understand.

**Move to Apex Triggers:**

- If there are complex logic or multiple process builders that can be consolidated, consider moving some of the logic to Apex triggers. Triggers can be more efficient for complex operations and allow for better error handling.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't decide if I think this is AI generated or not. At any rate though, if you are using AI to generate answers, that is not allowed on this site.

Comment: I spent ages writing this out, and is based on my own experience of working on a very heavy dependant automation org :(